# Baremetal hypervisors vs Virtual Box

Tags: kernel, virtual-machine, xen

I have mainly been using Virtual Box for a while but have recently started using Xen which as led me to questions about Type 1 hypervisors vs Type 2 hypervisors. I have read a lot about the differences but many things also seem contradictory and I am trying to find a better explanation.

Does a Type 1 hypervisor (Xen) act as a kernel, becoming the kernel that boots at runtime? 
If so then when installing Xen on Linux mint for example does the existing Linux installation become the first VM (dom0)?

Answer (score 0):

That's right, Xen is the first thing that boots. On a typically PC, it's either booted *via* GRUB or directly by the EFI. When you're starting from an existing installation, such as your Mint setup, that becomes Dom0 and its kernel boots in paravirtualised mode.